# Replacing urls in QGIS attribute table with images using python

Tags: pyqgis

With the help of python, I managed to build a small script that replaces all URLs in a text column with images using a delegate. The images where loaded from Microsoft SharePoint using an adapted version of request_ntlm.

```
import PyQt4
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth, HttpNtlmSspiAuth
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QTableView

class ImageDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self, parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        # Get Item Data
        url = index.model().data(index, QtCore.Qt.EditRole)

        if url != '':
            style = QtGui.QApplication.style()
            opt = QtGui.QStyleOptionGraphicsItem()
            opt.rect = option.rect
            r = requests.get(url, auth=HttpNtlmSspiAuth())
            data = r.content

            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
            pixmap.loadFromData(data)
            if option.rect.x() > 250:
                pixmap=pixmap.scaledToWidth(250)

            painter.drawPixmap(option.rect.x(), option.rect.y(),  pixmap)


dialog = iface.showAttributeTable(iface.activeLayer())
targetColumnIndex = 8 # how to find Index of column?
delegateImage = ImageDelegate(iface)

dialog.findChildren(QTableView)[0].setItemDelegateForColumn(targetColumnIndex, delegateImage)
dialog.findChildren(QTableView)[0].setColumnWidth(targetColumnIndex, 250 )
dialog.findChildren(QTableView)[0].verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(200)
```

What I couldn't manage by now: how to retrieve the index of a given column (see hardcoded targetColumnIndex in the code above) in the attribute table (QTableView) even when "colxy" is moved or some columns are hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone is interested, here's the answer:

```
dialog = iface.showAttributeTable(iface.activeLayer())

delegateImage = ImageDelegate(iface)
tableView = dialog.findChildren(QTableView)[0]
model = tableView.horizontalHeader().model()
for column in range(model.columnCount()):
    title = tableView.model().children()[0].headerData(column,QtCore.Qt.Horizontal,0)
    if title == 'colxy':
        targetColumnIndex = column
        break
```

Unfortunately, that brings me only a little step further.

Next question that comes to mind:
How can I respond to any index change of the image column? (i.e. when other columns are hidden or the column is moved) Are there any signals available? Or can I disable the context menu of the table header?

Comment: Looking at the amazing code you have written so far, you don't seem to require much explanation ;) [QgsVectorLayer.attributeTableConfig()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a1573aa629a70a47613b336bf10399a0e) and [QgsVectorLayer.configChanged](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsMapLayer.html#a261b397c51efe4a4d15e8b884930efa7)

Comment: Matthias, many thanks for for giving me credit! But i feel more like a Python rookie ;)